What is the maximum number of entries a array can in a Spark column can hold?
I've created a struct with the data of some columns combined. Large numbers of these structs now occur for my unique identifier values. I want to combine these structs into an array using collect_list.
Unfortunately, I'm getting errors like
java.lang.Exception: Results too large
at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.OutputAggregator$.maybeApplyOutputAggregation(OutputAggregator.scala:458)

So, how many elements (structs in my case) can an array in a Spark column contain?
Here's the Scala code I'm using
val compact_df = deliveries_df
  .withColumn("file_detail", struct($"file_id", $"delivery_seqno", $"file_path_name"))
  .groupBy('delivery_id, 'delivery_file_type)
  .agg(collect_list('file_detail).alias("file_details"))
display(compact_df)


com.databricks. is ain't Spark. Its some sort of vendor-specific extension, so perhaps you'd have better chances contacting them.

Arrays (and maps) are limited by the jvm - which an unsigned in at 2 billion worth.
It's also possible that the row / chunk limit of 2gb is also met before an individual array size is, given that each row is backed by a byte array.
edited based on feedback - as .show works it's just down to display - i.e. a Databricks workbook issue.

I checked the number of entries in my array of structs, and the biggest entry in the column of array of struct is an array which will contain 86'724 structs. So it seems something else the limiting factor, or the average entry size would be more than 23kB. Since the struct consists of an integer and a string, and the string is only a filename, this won't ever grow to 23k per struct.

if you use show instead does it work?  It could be a purely databricks limitation and nothing to do with your row or data chunk (collection of rows) size

Hi Chris, Great! Indeed it appears to be the display function. The DF.show command works, as does writing it to a table!

awesome, well at least you know and can raise it with Databricks.  I've edited my answer for that so people don't have to search for it.
